# Why does High Availability Group throw an error 35250?

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, alwayson

I have a problem with creating a new high availability group in SQL Server. At the end of creating High Availability Group, I get an error 35250.

I tried a lot of solution especially the solutions that are here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alwaysonpro/2013/12/09/create-availability-group-fails-with-error-35250-failed-to-join-the-database/

I know the endpoints are created and I know they use port 5022 and I know the port is open and I know the servers are listening to port 5022 and the endpoints have permission to connect, but when I run the query which is:

```
select
    r.replica_server_name, r.endpoint_URL,
    rs.connected_state_desc, rs.last_connect_error_description, 
    rs.last_connect_error_number, rs.last_connect_error_timestamp 
from 
    sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states rs 
join 
    sys.availability_replicas r on rs.replica_id = r.replica_id
where 
    rs.is_local = 1
```

In the secondary replica I get disconnected with error 10054 but in primary it is connected.

Even when I change the servers again in the secondary it disconnects me. I mean the servers are not important at all.Always the secondary servers are disconnected and I don't know why.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4667/fix-sql-server-alwayson-error-35250-failed-to-join-the-availability-group/

Comment: This solution is concerned with the firewall problems .I've already fixed that